# Determine if BitmapFactory.decodeStream() succeeded without errors

Tags: android, bitmap

I am downloading bitmaps from the internet by using `BitmapFactory.decodeStream()` inside an AsyncTask. In my app, I have a list view of images and I only want to download the bitmaps that the user can see and cancel all download requests for bitmaps that the user has scrolled pass. After a download is complete, I cache the bitmap so I don't have to download it again. To cancel bitmap downloads, I call `AsyncTask.cancel(true)`.

The problem is that sometimes `BitmapFactory.decodeStream()` will output a warning that an InterruptedIOException has occurred (because I canceled the Task while it was downloading) but it will not actually throw the exception. Normally when this happens, the function returns with a half loaded bitmap. Unfortunately, since the bitmap returned is not null the application just assumes the download was successful and caches this half downloaded bitmap. From this point on, the user will be stuck with the half loaded bitmap until the cache is cleared.

So my question is, is there a way to check if `BitmapFactory.decodeStream()` actually succeeded in downloading the bitmap?

Comment: I'm having a similar problem, except in my case after it logs the warning in the log file it SIGINTs my app and takes it down hard.  I have a try/catch block that should catch the exception (it isn't thrown back to my level).  decodeStream() never returns in my case...the app just dies.  This has to be mishandling of the task interrupt in library code, so I don't see anything that can be done about it.  I have to use "cancel(false)" and endure the computational delay for the stream decode (a network download operation) to complete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I did not figure out a way to tell if `BitmapFactory.decodeStream()` completed without errors, I did find a workaround. I simply check whether the task has been canceled before calling `BitmapFactory.decodeStream()` and after calling `BitmapFactory.decodeStream()` to determine if the task has been canceled during the `BitmapFactory.decodeStream()` call. If it has, I simply assume that `BitmapFactory.decodeStream()` failed (which it probably has) and perform the necessary clean up code to ensure the bitmap never makes it to the cache.